# Generate New Keystore with Google provided SHA1 fingerprint

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-keystore, android-app-signing

I generated signed apk and uploaded to playstore. Now, I lost my keystore and contacted Google for resetting my keystore. They had given me new SHA1 fingerprint. Then they asked me to generate new keystore by using the fingerprint provided by Google team.
I tried all the possible ways and Googled it but no luck.
I gone through lot of answers in SO and I followed steps given in the answer, but didn't able to generate keystore with new SHA1 fingerprint.
Can someone help with steps to generate Keystore with Google provided SHA1 fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generate a keystore from just a fingerprint.

If you have enrolled in App Signing by Play and have asked Google to reset your key, then they would ask *you* to create a new keystore and to provide *them* with the certificate fingerprint. So you should be the one with the keystore at this stage.

In case you haven't enrolled in App Signing by Play, then there is no way to reset the key. I don't know what Google support team told you, but if they gave you a certificate fingerprint, then maybe it was so you could try to find the keystore that matches the certificate.

Regardless, Google cannot provide you with a keystore that will allow you to sign your app. Either you've enrolled in App Signing by Play and you can reset it (and you will create a new keystore then), or you will have to create a new app with a new package name.

If you've forgotten if you're enrolled in App Signing by Play, you can check it in the *App Signing* page of the Play Console.

Hope that helps,